# ArrayList<Integer> getDeclaredMethod("add", Integer.class) throws NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

```
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
intList.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add", Integer.class); // throws NoSuchMethodException

//where as
intList.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("add", Object.class); // is just fine.
```

Of course in this case I want the first one to work. Or at least figure out how get a method from a generic type parameter.

When looping over the declared methods the `add` method does explicitly say Object:

```
public boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)
```

My guess is I am missing something simple.

Comment: Type erasure. At runtime, generics don't exist, so the parameter type of `add` is Object.

Answer (score 0):

Because the declaration is `add(E e)`. `ArrayList<E>` is a generic type and it has no knowledge about the actual type.

See [for example this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E))

So the closest it can guess the type of `E` is `Object`